# Pointer to an array of pointers in Pascal

Tags: pointers, pascal, dynamic-variables

I don't know how to access the content of an array of pointers by a pointer. Here's an example:

```
Type
    PInteger = ^Integer;
    IntegerArrayP = array of PInteger;
    PIntegerArrayP = ^IntegerArray;

var
    variable: Integer;
    parrp: PIntegerArrayP;
    arrp: IntegerArrayP;
begin
    SetLength(arrp, 5);
    parrp := @arrp;
    For variable := Low(arrp) to High(arrp) do
    begin
        arrp[variable] := New(PInteger);
        (parrp^)[variable]^ := variable;
        WriteLn('parrp: ', arrp[variable]^);
    end;
end.
```

In my opinion it should be done like this `(ptabp^)[variable]^ := variable;`
But I guess I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Parens might be omitted.
What pascal compiler do you use? Proper usage of `New` routine:

```
 New(arrp[variable]) ;
 parrp^[variable]^ := variable;
```

P.S. Do you really need these pointer types here?

P.P.S. Now I see an error:
PIntegerArrayP = ^IntegerArray**P**;

Comment: I'm using free pascal. I've also tried to compile it on an online compiler. Check it out here: http://ideone.com/rSkhTQ

Comment: Well I don't need all of these pointer types. I'm just practising.

Comment: You mixed common type and your own type by accident. See addition